# Position and Velocity

Tags: ros, position, geometry-msgs, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a standard-ish message that represents an object's 3d position and 3d velocity?

[insert Heisenberg joke here]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30430/position-and-velocity/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-03-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[geometry_msgs/Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) is for velocities, [geometry_msgs/Pose](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) is for position and orientation.

[nav_msgs/Odometry](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) contains both together with covariances (whereas designed for other purpose).

If you just need Twist and Pose together, you can [easily design your own message](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv).

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a message called JointMessage under common_msgs/sensor_msgs. It is defined as follows:

```
Header header

string[] name
float64[] position
float64[] velocity
float64[] effort
```

I'm unclear as to what name means but the other parameters are defined as:

```
# The state of each joint (revolute or prismatic) is defined by:
#  * the position of the joint (rad or m),
#  * the velocity of the joint (rad/s or m/s) and 
#  * the effort that is applied in the joint (Nm or N).
```

Since these parameters are arrays they should suffice for your needs.

---

Originally posted by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) with karma: 328 on 2012-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-03-26**:
I would not recommend using JointState to describe object position an velocity, there are other msgs that are designed for that. (The `name` field in JointState contains the joint's names.)